# Sass Loop through array and present variable

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to loop through my color list in order to change the background color. But the following fails.

```
$speech-bubble-default: $colors-chalk;
$speech-bubble-blush: $colors-blush;
$speech-bubble-brick: $colors-brick;
$speech-bubble-pink: $colors-pink;
$speech-bubble-slate: $colors-slate;

$colors-list: blush brick default pink slate;

  @each $current-color in $colors-list {
    &.speech-bubble--#{$current-color} {
      background-color: $speech-bubble--#{$current-color};

      &::after {
        border-bottom-color: $speech-bubble--#{$current-color};
      }
    }
  }
```

> 'Error: Undefined variable: "$speech-bubble--"

Is there a way to get this working in loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you have to got this simpler. I would create a list to manage colors. This way you are properly creating variables and avoid repeating code.

```
$colors-list:(
  default: 'chalk',
  blush: 'blush',
  brick: 'brick',
  pink: 'pink',
  slate: 'slate'
);
```

If you want a more descriptive and semantic way to separate the name of the color to its functionality, you can do a nested list of variables of colors like this:

```
  $chalk: 'chalk';
  $blush: 'blush';
  $brick: 'brick';
  $pink: 'pink';
  $slate: 'slate';


$colors-list:(
  default: $chalk,
  blush: $blush,
  brick: $brick,
  pink: $pink,
  slate: $slate
);
```

The problem in your code is that you are trying to reference variables by interpolation `#{}` and [variable name interpolation](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/132) is not supported by SASS. Variables are called by its whole name. You also are repeating colors lists.

Why not:

```
@each $key,$val in $colors-list{
  .speech-bubble--#{$key} {
    background-color: #{$val};
  }
}
```