# Is it possible to loop through multiple media queries with a SASS for loop?

Tags: css, sass

For example I have code that looks like this

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .t-#{$i} {
    top: 1% * $i;
  }
}
```

But I have 6 sets of media queries I want this to be applied to. For example, here's two:

```
@media #{$breakpoint-small} { 
  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .t-#{$i} {
      top: 1% * $i;
    }
  }
}
```

```
@media #{$breakpoint-large} { 
  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .t-#{$i} {
      top: 1% * $i;
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally I could put these into a function that runs each of the breakpoints, small, medium, large etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your breakpoints into a list, and then iterate over that list.

```
$breakpoints:(
  large: 'min-width: 900px',
  medium: 'min-width: 600px',
  small: 'min-width: none'
);

@each $key,$val in $breakpoints{
  @media (#{$val}) { 
    @for $i from 1 through 100 {
      .t-#{$i} {
        top: 1% * $i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43826683/453277) was helpful.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks.